# SQL in Excel return field if match condition

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I need to return project name if contract has only one project, otherwise return count of project.

```
Contract, Project, Rev
con1    , prj1   , 5
con1    , prj2   , 20
con2    , prj3   , 30
```

Likely result:

```
Contract, Project, Sum of Rev 
con1    , 2      , 25
con2    , prj3   , 30
```

So far I have this:

```
SELECT Contract, IIF(Count(Project)=1,Project,COUNT(Project)) AS 
       ProjectCount, SUM(Rev) AS Sum of Rev 
FROM Table1 
GROUP BY Contract
```

[image: Error picture]

I have also tried replace Project with VLOOKUP function, but it was only just as text, not calculated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT Contract, 
       IIF(Count(Project) = 1, MAX(Project), COUNT(Project)) AS ProjectCount,
       SUM(Rev) AS Sum of Rev 
FROM Table1 
GROUP BY Contract ;
```

If you have only one project, then the maximum value *is* the name of the project.

You may need to convert `MAX(Project)` to a string.  The standard syntax would be:  `CAST(MAX(Project) as VARCHAR(32))`.  However, that syntax might be different in the database you are using.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you very much.